# How are support packages on compute engine billed?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I am load testing on Google compute engine at the moment.  We're considering moving our code onto compute engine and then migrating to app engine.

I've got some questions regarding what is possible on the platform and I'd like to buy a support package.  Only problem is I'm currently using a test project and not the final project which we will be using.  Therefore I'd like to know the following before I sign up for support.

Can I cancel the subscription for support or change it or is it an annual contract?

If I get support on one project can I migrate this support package to another project?

Perhaps, could I cancel the support package on one project and start it up again on another?

If I cancel a support package will I be billed for the whole month?

What will happen to my 'Europe' App engine apps if my support package is canceled and moved?

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silver and Gold support packages are billed monthly and can be cancelled at any time. Since the Platinum support package can only purchased directly from Google sales, I imagine some type of contract is signed. More info here: https://cloud.google.com/support/

Since the support package can be cancelled at any time, if you wish to migrate it to another project you can simply cancel it on the first one and then purchase it on the second one.

Yes, you will be billed for the whole month if you cancel your support package before the end of the month.

All apps remain functional regardless of the support package.